# File Content viewer on browser using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to view **content** of uploaded files on browser in asp.net ? And is it possible to view contents of all type of files using common code ? Or there is any free project there ?

Thanks..

Comment: I used this ages ago: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebFileManager.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to see the content of **any file** as that would require the browser in question to have a plugin to display a particular file. Take for example a MS Project File, a Corel Draw File an Auto CAD, what have you. The browser won't display those since AFAIK, there's not a plugin provided for these files that can be used by the browser to embed a viewer in it.

The browser, in general, will happily display PDFs (provided Acrobat Reader is installed), Images, TXT files and a couple others.

Therefore, you can perfectly read all the files doing something like:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("PhysicalPathToFiles");
GridView1.DataSource=info.GetFiles();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And set up your GrdiView1 markup to only bind the FileName property and everything else you need. You'd want to construct a hyperlink on this column so that when the file name is clicked, the user is asked to download/view the file, depending on the file type.

Let's say you bound all the files to the Gridview as I explained above. Having a GridViewColumn like this, should allow the user to click on any file and see it inside the browser.

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn
                 HeaderText="File Name"
                 DataNavigateUrlField="Name"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="UploadedFiles/{0}"
                 DataTextField="Name"
                 />
```

Where `UploadedFiles` is the virtual directory inside your app that holds these files.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to view content of the file on browser.

Comment: @Harikrishna: Not all files will be "viewable" inside the browser. Imagine a user uploaded a CorelDraw file to the app. The browser won't be able to display it inside it. The browser, in general, will happily display PDFs, Images & TXT files. You didn't say what type of files are you allowing the users to upload, hence my answer.

Comment: It is, but I want to display content of the files like pdf, text file, word, excel which is generally used to upload. So what can I do for that ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: By creating links to the virtual path of the file, as I explained, it **will be displayed** inside the browser. Let me update my answer and explain a bit better what I mean.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll wait. And as you said before I want to display content of  PDFs (provided Acrobat Reader is installed), Images, TXT files and a couple others which browser supports.

Comment: Can I see the content of the file on the browser with the help of the code you have written in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the user to view the files inline, you will need to stream the file to the user and set some values in the header.

We usually perform this action using an HTTP handler mapped to a "virtual" page (i.e. Download.aspx) so that it can be called from the client side in a popup window without affecting the calling page.

This mechanism can be used to either download or view a file inline.

Here is a description of the download process implemented in the StreamFileToUser method in the class at the end of this answer:

If the caller requests a download, then we check a collection of mime types to determine whether or not the file contains a supported mimetype, which means that it has a chance of being displayed inline to the user.

If the mime type is found, we use the inline directive to ask the browser to show the file to the user. If the browser doesn't support inlining for this mime type, the user will be prompted to download.

If we don't find a mime type, then a straight download command will be issued.

You can get the complete list of mime types within IIS (assuming 7+) by opening IIS manager, selecting the web server icon, and double-clicking the Mime Types icon.

Here is an example of the HTTP handler class:

```
public class DownloadRequestHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to process the incoming request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oContext"></param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext oContext)
    {
        try
        {
            string sFileName = null;
            string sSourceFilePath = null;

            // Should add existence checking here
            sFileName = oContext.Request.QueryString["FileName"];

            // Assume that the files are stored in the relative directory Files. Should add existence checking here
            sSourceFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(oContext.Server.MapPath("Files"), sFileName);

            StreamFileToUser(GenerateStandardMimeList(), sSourceFilePath, sFileName, oContext.Response, false, false);
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException theException)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            SendErrorToUser(oContext.Response, theException.Message);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method streams a file to a user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cMimeTypes">The set of known mimetypes. This is only needed when the file is not being downloaded.</param>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <param name="sFileNameForUser"></param>
    /// <param name="theResponse"></param>
    /// <param name="fDownload"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public bool StreamFileToUser(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> cMimeTypes, string sFileName, string sFileNameForUser, HttpResponse theResponse, bool fDownload = true, bool fOkToDeleteFile = false)
    {
        // Exceptions are handled by the caller

        bool fDontEndResponse = false;

        sFileNameForUser = CleanFileName(sFileNameForUser);

        // Ensure there is nothing else in the response
        try
        {
            try
            {
                // Remove what other controls may have been put on the page
                theResponse.ClearContent();
                // Clear any headers
                theResponse.ClearHeaders();
            }
            catch (System.Web.HttpException theException)
            {
                // Ignore this exception, which could occur if there were no HTTP headers in the response
            }

            bool fFoundIt = false;

            if (!fDownload)
            {
                string sExtension = null;

                sExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sFileNameForUser);
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sExtension)))
                {
                    sExtension = sExtension.Replace(".", "");
                    if (cMimeTypes.ContainsKey(sExtension))
                    {
                        theResponse.ContentType = cMimeTypes[sExtension];
                        theResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + sFileNameForUser);
                        fFoundIt = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!fFoundIt)
            {
                theResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                theResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileNameForUser);
            }

            theResponse.TransmitFile(sFileName);

            // Ensure the file is properly flushed to the user
            theResponse.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            // If the caller wants, delete the file before the response is terminated
            if (fOkToDeleteFile)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(sFileName);
            }
        }

        // Ensure the response is closed
        theResponse.Close();

        if (!fDontEndResponse)
        {
            try
            {
                theResponse.End();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method generates a standard list of extension to content-disposition tags
    /// The key for each item is the file extension without the leading period. The value 
    /// is the content-disposition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> GenerateStandardMimeList()
    {
        // Exceptions are handled by the caller.

        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> cItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        cItems.Add("jpeg", "image/jpeg");
        cItems.Add("jpg", "image/jpeg");
        cItems.Add("pdf", "application/pdf");
        cItems.Add("csv", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        cItems.Add("doc", "application/msword");
        cItems.Add("docx", "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12");
        cItems.Add("xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        cItems.Add("xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel.12");

        return cItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method removes all invalid characters from the specified file name.
    /// Note that ONLY the file name should be passed, not the directory name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public string CleanFileName(string sFileName)
    {
        // Exceptions are handled by the caller

        // If there are any invalid characters in the file name
        if (sFileName.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) >= 0)
        {
            // Strip them out (split to remove the characters, then rejoin the pieces into one string)
            return string.Join("", sFileName.Split(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
        }
        else
        {
            return sFileName;
        }
    }

    public void SendErrorToUser(HttpResponse theResponse, string sError)
    {
        // Note that errors are handled by the caller

        sError = "<script>alert(\"" + sError.Replace("\"", "").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n") + "\");</script>";
        // Ensure there is nothing else in the response
        theResponse.Clear();
        theResponse.Write(sError);
        theResponse.Flush();
    }
}
```

In your web.config, add the following line to the `httphandlers` section, replacing the namespace as appropriate:

```
    <add path="download.aspx" verb="*" type="MyWebApp.DownloadRequestHandler, MyWebApp" validate="false" />
```

Then your download request is:

```
download.aspx?FileName=thefile.pdf
```

and the above code assumes that the files are stored in the Files subdirectory of the website.

Comment: Not necessary to add anything to the headers, that would be the case if you want the user to always download the file (by adding content-disposition) but to display it, clicking on the link is enough.

Comment: @Icarus: It actually depends on how the link is presented; if it is a link directly to a file in the web site, then you are correct. However, if it is a link to an HTTP handler (which I added a blurb on at the end), then you definitely must specify the content disposition.

Comment: @competent_tech Can we view word file and pdf file also using this code ?

Comment: @Icarus I cannot see content of the file using the code in your answer. I think I am missing something, how to add virtual directory in application ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Absolutely, assuming the user has the applications installed and they are configured for inline viewing. Acrobat has an option that allows the end user to turn off the inline display. I will update the mime types to include some of the common office doc types.

Comment: @harikrishna you do it from IIS. Control panel -> admin tools-> IIS management -> right click your app-> click "add virtual directory" and follow the steps.

Comment: @competent_tech First of all I have to call the method StreamFileToUser, is it ? And in that method what to pass for HttpResponse ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: I have added the complete download request handler to the answer so that you can see exactly how it is used.

Comment: @competent_tech I found this error by compiling code you have provided (1)'ASP.default_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found to override.(2)'ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)': no suitable method found to override (3)'ASP.default_aspx' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable

Comment: @Harikrishna: It sounds like you added the code to default.aspx; this needs to be a new class file that isn't a page or usercontrol, just a plain class file.

Comment: @competent_tech ok now it's complied successfully but there is no any output. What to pass for httpresponse in the method StreamFileToUser()  ? Is it this.Response ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Yes, unless you implement the HTTP Handler, in which case it is context.Response where context is the parameter passed to IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest.

Comment: @competent_tech, sorry I am totally new to these all things so sorry for my bad knowledge to all these. But what to write for the argument for httpresponse ? I could not understand what you wrote in your last comment. sorry for that.

Comment: @competent_tech, The file can be downloaded through this code but cannot view, because there is an error where theResponse.End(); line got executed. So there might be problem with theResponse.End();

Comment: @Harikrishna: Ok, I have revised the answer to show the complete downloadrequest handler class. If you implement as I have described in the answer, you do not need any additional code. If you have included the code in a page of your own, then you need to use this.Response in the call to StreamFileToUser.

Comment: @Harikrishna: Response.End will almost always throw an exception, which can be safely ignored. You can also try leaving that out if you want, but if you have this included in a page, the page content may also be included in the downloaded file, which is not desirable.

Comment: @competent_tech, Ok it's done thank you very very much for your great help, but the file is opened on the browser by by windows. I want to show the content of the file in the browser like when we attach the file to the gmail and we can see that content as google document. I wanted to do the thing like that.

Comment: @Harikrishna: What is the file name? And are you passing false to the download parameter in StreamFileToUser?

Comment: @competent_tech, No fdownload paramater in the StreamFileToUser method is always true.

Comment: @Harikrishna: Change that to false; that way the file will be viewed if the mime type is in the list or downloaded if it isn't.

Comment: @competent_tech If I set it to false then there will no output like there is a message in browser that "The webpage at http://localhost:3312/WebSite3/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Comment: @Harikrishna: Hmmm... It sounds like there may be an exception. Can you debug through to see where it is occurring?

Comment: Yes, its occurred at theResponse.End() in the method StreamFileToUser

Comment: Ok, change fDontEndResponse = false to fDontEndResponse = true

Comment: @competent_tech there is no change in the output, same problem is there. Even if that Response.End() is not executed there is no output.

Comment: @competent_tech I can view notepad file content in the browser using your code but I tried  to view content docx file using code but cannot view, it is being downloaded so please help me to do that.

Comment: @Harikrishna: This is something that has to be enabled on the end user's machine. See this thread for more info and ways to accomplish this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/b4ed8ffc-3c89-4b9b-9a25-71a22dca2f04/